# RedisTemplate + Lua script: command arguments must be strings or integers

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, lua

I want to atomically insert or update a key, insert this key into an index and, optionally, increment a count. To this end, I wrote the following Lua script. In this script, `KEYS[1]` is the element key, `KEYS[2]` is the index key, `ARGV[1]` is the object stored at `KEYS[1]` and `ARGV[2]` is a score.

```
if not redis.call('EXISTS', KEYS[1]) then
  redis.call('INCR', KEYS[2] .. ":num");
end
redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]);
redis.call('ZADD', KEYS[2] .. ":idx", tonumber(ARGV[2]), KEYS[1]);
```

To access Redis, I use a `RedisTemplate<String, Object>` instance which uses `GenericFastJsonRedisSerializer` to serialize values. A small working example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        configuration.setHostName("localhost");
        configuration.setPort(6379);
        LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(configuration);
        connectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericFastJsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setDefaultSerializer(new GenericFastJsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericFastJsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new GenericFastJsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericFastJsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();

        RedisScript<Object> script = RedisScript.of(new PathResource(Paths.get("my-script.lua"))); // <- above script
        template.execute(script, Arrays.asList("value-key", "index-key"), new Object(), 1.0);
    }
}
```

However, when I run the Lua script, I get the following error:

```
@user_script: 14: Lua redis() command arguments must be strings or integers
```

I suppose, this is because the serializer also serializes the score, so Lua cannot read it as number anymore. Hence, how can I avoid that the serializer is applied to all arguments, and only translating my object to JSON?

Comment: Lua script itself is fine and produces expected result if you run it as: `redis-cli evalsha $(cat test.lua | redis-cli -x script load) 2 key1 key2 10 11` so try to check how it is being serialized in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my way to resolve the problem.

before:

```
template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
template.setValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
```

after:

```
template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(String.class));
```

Comment: I didn't used `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer`.

Comment: I just provide an idea.I use GenericToStringSerializer to resolve the problem.you can try.

Comment: GenericFastJsonRedisSerializer should have caused the redis value to change.So your Lua script can not read the value.

Comment: So, when I take `new GenericToStringSerializer<>(String.class)`, I get `No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Object] to type [java.lang.String]`.

Comment: However, using Jackson instead of FastJson works. Apparently, this issue is somehow related to how FastJson serializes the data. Anyway, our company ditched FastJson for security issues, so this question isn't actually very relevant to me anymore.